# Updated from 19.04 to 19.10 and errors everywhere

Tags: dpkg, 19.10

Updated to 19.10 because I thought it would be better - I was wrong. The dock is gone, the style is somewhat messed up, GRUB's config broke, and now whenever I run sudo apt update or upgrade, I get this error.

Can anyone please help? I'm honestly really worried about having to do a full reinstall and it would be appreciated if anyone here has knowledge on fixing it. Thanks, Ask Ubuntu!

https://markdownshare.com/raw/efcdde0f-17ba-494d-98a9-7737bbe3c7bc

Comment: Your 19.04 installation was not clean. Upgrades can go wrong. In your case, best to backup your important data, and do a fresh install of 19.10. Much better long term result.

Comment: Seems similar to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031066/errors-during-upgrade-from-17-10-to-18-04-shim-signed-and-grub-efi-amd64-signed/1032156#1032156